# how to handle (0 rows affected) exception in python while updating the record into the sql server

Tags: python, sql-server

```
sqlConnection.execute(sa_text(sqlquery).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Comment: *0 rows affected* means that no rows were updated because a row was not found to be updated, most likely. The solution to that is to fix the UPDATE statement so that the conditions for the update actually exist, and the row can be updated.

Comment: i want capture daily record into one table then from my python script i am transferring into the other table, but in case other table record not present which i am trying to update then that scenario i  need to handle the above exception , how i can handle?

Comment: Edit that information into your question where it belongs. It should have been part of your original question. You can find the [edit] link beneath the tags in the bottom left corner of your post.